# Nginx rewrite rules additional arguments

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm breaking my head on Nginx rewrite rules while migrating from Apache to Nginx.

I had .htaccess rewrite rules that made `/search/foo+bar/2&pricerange=20-50` to `search.php?search=foo+bar&page=2&pricerange=20-50`
and I could access all the arguments like you would expect with `$_GET['search'], $_GET['page'] and $_GET['pricerange']`

But now with Nginx I have issues with this appended arguments like pricerange. Whenever I visit `/search/foo+bar/2&pricerange=20-50` it does not translate the pricerange argument.
And when I visit the same url without the page number the pricerange argument gets added to the search argument. But only when I'm using more than one word concatenated with +'s.

My current Nginx rewrite rules:

`location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    rewrite ^/search/(.*)/(.*)/$ /search?search=$1&page=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/search/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /search?search=$1&page=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/search/(.*)/$ /search?search=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/search/(.*)/?$ /search?search=$1 last;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET arguments begin after the '?' 
 
/search/foo+bar/2&pricerange=20-50 
You need to replace '&' with '?' or rewrite rule
`rewrite ^/search/(.*)/([0-9]+)&pricerange=(.*)$ /search?search=$1&page=$2&pricerange=$3 last;`